# загрузка системы в tt1

Tags: ubuntu, uefi, dell

После обновления системы ubuntu 14.05 lts перезагрузил ноутбук. После этого система грузится в консольном варианте, перейти в графический режим не получается. При нажатии на cntrl+alt+f7 или cntrl+f7 остается черное окно и вернуться обратно в консольный режим не удается, команды типа cntrl+alt+f1 не работают. При установке обновлений открылось окно с отключением UEFI или что-то в этом роде, запрашивал какой-то пароль, я так понимаю, что он указан в биосе, но я решил не делать ничего и отменил установку этого компонента, далее перезагрузил ноутбук и на этом все. Какие варианты выхода есть?

Answer (score 0):

Исключительно методом "научного тыка" я решил войти в биос и отключить параметр "secure boot". Перезагрузился и все работает.